# Ember CLI - Error when using moment.js in route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have imported moment.js into my project and it seems to work just fine in my controllers but for some reason it is not working in my routes.

Controller:

```
// controllers/users.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    date: function() {
        alert(moment().format('X'));
    }.property()

    ...
});
```

Route:

```
// routes/users.js 
// (Error: /routes/users.js: line 5, col 29, 'moment' is not defined.
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var data = { start: moment().startOf('month').startOf('day').format('X') };
        return this.store.find('event', data);
    }
});
```

Brocfile:

```
var app = new EmberApp();

app.import('vendor/moment/moment.js');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is a JsHint Error. You may want to add the following comment to your Route code.

```
/* global moment:true */
import Ember from "ember";
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Also (from [ember-cli documentation](http://ember-cli.com)):

> If you want to use external libraries that write to a global namespace (e.g. moment.js), you need to add those to the `predef` section of your project’s `.jshintrc` file and set its value to true. If you use the lib in tests, need to add it to your `tests/.jshintrc` file, too.

Then you don't have to do it to every file your using moment.js in.