# Using browsers navigator results in JShint error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, jshint

I'm using the globally available `navigator` object that the browser exposes in an Ember-CLI project (aka, with ES6 syntax) and I'd like to avoid getting errors when referencing this valid global object.

I saw this suggestion: [Ember CLI - Error when using moment.js in route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771540/ember-cli-error-when-using-moment-js-in-route/24771833#24771833) and tried added ['navigator'] to the `predef` definition in the `.jshintrc` file. Didn't seem to have any impact. I also then put the following into the JS file itself:

```
/* global navigator: false */
```

That worked but I still feel the .jshintrc alternative would be nice. Is there a way to achieve this? Why didn't my attempt have the desired results in the same way that the *momentjs* example did?

---

BTW, here is the default setting that Ember-CLI puts in:

```
"predef": [
    "document",
    "window",
    "-Promise"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answer isn't wrong, exactly, but it does have the wrong format, and doesn't make clear that there is a seperate `.jshintrc` file for tests. In my case, this was the one that needed to be updated.

In `tests/.jshintrc` (which is different from the main `.jshintrc`) add `"navigator"` to the `"predef"` array, like so:

```
{
  "predef": [
    "document",
    "window",
    "navigator",
    "location",
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.jshintrc` file, you should do it that way:

```
{
  "predef": {
    "navigator": true
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: makes sense that it would be a dictionary structure like you suggest but Ember-CLI has default values which I would be hesitant to play around with where it's treating `predef` as an array. Are there more than one syntaxes supported?

Comment: ok, it had to change a while ago and you're right, it's an array now :) but I've created a new app using `ember new app` and tried to add `abc` to this array, then I ran tests and it worked! without adding `abc` to `predef` I have a jshint error though. So maybe you're changing it in a wrong `.jshintrc` file? there are two separate ones for source and tests